# Show/Hide CSS Ignored When Inside an SLDS Grid Column

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, lightning-design-system

I'm just trying to get a simple show/hide experiment running using the code below. It runs fine when the code is outside the SLDS grid. However when I place the div inside a grid column, the console log "test" is displayed but the div remains visible. Am I missing something?? ..Thanks

## Component

```
<aura:component >    
    <lightning:button label="Toggle" onclick="{!c.doInit}"/> 
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col">
            <div class="slds-box">
                <div aura:id="detailDiv" >
                    <c:ShowHideCmpFilter Message="Detail"/>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div> 
<aura:component >
```

## CSS

```
.THIS.toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

## Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("test");        
        var toggleText = component.find("detailDiv");        
        $A.util.toggleClass(toggleText, "toggle");        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a space in your CSS, `.THIS.some-class` refers only to top-level elements. To specify child elements, there needs to be a space:

```
.THIS .toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

This will correctly toggle the contents as you expect.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! ..I remember reading about the space but never really understood the purpose. Now I do :)

Comment: @Jay You'll end up using both methods, depending on if you're selecting top level elements or not, so make sure to remember this.

Comment: The part about `.THIS` only residing on top-level elements will come up a lot when customizing CSS in Lightning. I believe `<aura:component>` does not put any sort of wrapper element around your component. As such, if there is more than one top-level node, each will be tagged with that CSS class. Depending on the use case, you may find it makes the most sense to wrap the entire component in a `<div>` or `<span>` as appropriate, so that your entire component is one single DOM node inside the parent.