# How to hide/show a button on/after init?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've got this component which got a form:

```
<aura:component controller="starWarsCallout">

<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

<aura:attribute name="characters" type="SWCharacter__c[]"/>

<aura:attribute name="newSWCharacter" type="SWCharacter__c"
     default="{ 'sobjectType': 'SWCharacter__c',
                    'Name': '',
                    'Height__c': 0,
                    'SkinColor__c': '',
                    'Gender__c': '',
                    'Planet__c': ''}"/>
    
<aura:attribute name="response" type="Map"/>

<aura:attribute name="CharacterName" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="CharacterHeight" type="Integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="CharacterSkinColor" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="CharacterPlanet" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="CharacterGender" type="String"/>   

<aura:attribute name="ListOfFilms" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="ListOfSpecies" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="ListOfVehicles" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="ListOfStarships" type="String[]"/>

<!--Header -->
<div class="slds-m-around--medium">
    <!--Search Box -->
    <lightning:input type="search" label="Enter character ID" 
                     aura:id="characterID"  
                     onchange="{!c.APICallout}"/>

    <!--iterate the list of Films-->    
    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">List Of Films</h3>
    <ul class="slds-list--dotted">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListOfFilms}" var="film">
            <li>{!film}</li>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
    
    <!--iterate the list of Species-->    
    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">List Of Species</h3>
    <ul class="slds-list--dotted">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListOfSpecies}" var="specie">
            <li>{!specie}</li>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>

    <!--iterate the list of Vehicles-->
    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">List Of Vehicles</h3>
    <ul class="slds-list--dotted">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListOfVehicles}" var="vehicle">
            <li>{!vehicle}</li>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>

    <!--iterate the list of StarShips-->
    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">List Of StarShips</h3>
    <ul class="slds-list--dotted">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListOfStarships}" var="starship">
            <li>{!starship}</li>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
</div>


    <!-- BOXED AREA -->
    <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--small">
    <legend id="characterform" class="slds-text-heading--small 
      slds-p-vertical--medium">
      Add Character
    </legend>
        <!-- CREATE NEW CHARACTER FORM -->
        <form class="slds-form--stacked">          
            <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="peopleform" label="Character Name"
                             name="characterName"
                             value="{!v.CharacterName}"
                             required="true"/> 
            <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="peopleform" label="Height"
                             name="characterHeight"
                             value="{!v.CharacterHeight}"/>
            <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="peopleform" label="Gender"
                             name="characterGender"
                             value="{!v.CharacterGender}"/>
            <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="characterform" label="Planet"
                             name="characterPlanet"
                             value="{!v.CharacterPlanet}"/>
            <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="characterform" label="Skin Color"  
                             name="characterSkincolor"
                             value="{!v.CharacterSkinColor}"/>
            <lightning:button label="Create Star Wars Character" aura:id="createButton"
                              class="slds-m-top--medium"
                              variant="brand"
                              onclick="{!c.clickCreate}"/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
 </aura:component>
```

and I want this button to be hidden

```
<lightning:button label="Create Star Wars Character" aura:id="createButton"
                              class="slds-m-top--medium"
                              variant="brand"
                              onclick="{!c.clickCreate}"/>
```

on init ....

I've got the init handler on the top

and I'm doing this inside the init function:

```
 doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        var toggleButton = component.find("createButton");
        $A.util.toggleClass(toggleButton, "toggle");
    },
```

this is the css:

```
.THIS.toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

as read in the documentation .... but not working, button is still there when the forms initializes :/

Any help to make this button disapear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is basically you because you should have `.THIS .toogle` with a space between them - found this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197212/show-hide-css-ignored-when-inside-an-slds-grid-column) that explains better than I do.

This becomes:

```css
.THIS .toogle {
    display: none
}
```

But one extra suggestion: hidden button and other elements usually don't look great, so, instead, you should disable the button. That can be done simply binding the disabled attribute to a new or existing component attribute, see below:
Attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="startedCallout" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

Button

```
<lightning:button label="Create Star Wars Character" aura:id="createButton"
                                  class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                  variant="brand"
                                  onclick="{!c.clickCreate}"
                                  disabled="{!v.startedCallout}"/>
```

And then on the controller method `APICallout` you can set this attribute to true:

```js
({
    APICallout : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.startedCallout", true);
        //make callout, here just adding a sleep to show that it will enable the button back after 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function () {
            component.set("v.startedCallout", false);
        }, 5000);
    }
})
```

Comment: You are the BEST :D

Comment: Jeferson! One more question bro : Why is the button enabled on init ? Shouldn't it be disabled sience this is set  disabled="{!v.startedCallout}" and startedCallout is false by default ?? I don't get this ... I'm trying to disable it on init

Comment: I disabled only when a call out started and has not finished, my bad. To disable a button the Boolean (startedCallout) must be true. So, if that's is what you want, change the name of the variable to what it makes more sense and the default value to true.